# Why the compiler look for the methods in the parent class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm getting error, parent' does not contain a definition for 'Print' and no extension method 'Print' accepting a first argument of type 'parent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            parent p1 = new child();
            p1.Print();
        }
    }
    //Parent Class
    public class parent
    {
    }

    //Child Class
    public class child : parent
    {
        public void Print() { }
    }
```

Comment: I'confused in                                                                                                                  parent p1 = new child();
        p1.Print();

        parent p2 = new parent();
        p2.Print();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is right: the `parent` class does not have a definition for method `Print`. Even though the object assigned to `p1` does have a `Print`, the compiler has no way of knowing it from the declaration of `p1`, and it is not allowed to use the initializer to figure it out.

In order to help the compiler do what you want it to do, you need to do one of the following:

1. Give `parent` a *virtual* method `Print` with the same signature as in `child`, and add `override` to the definition in the `child`
2. Declare an interface that has `Print` method, and make `parent` implement it
3. Declare `p1` of type `child`
4. Add an explicit cast of `p1` to `child` before making the call
5. Declare `p1` of type `dynamic`.

If you take approaches 1, 2, 3, or 4, C# would be able to check the presence of `Print` on the `p1` object at compile time. If you take approach 5, the compiler will defer the checking to runtime, at which point CLR would have to perform an additional search for the `Print` method, and either call it or throw a runtime error.

Comment: Thank a ton for If you take approach 5, the compiler will defer the checking to runtime, at which point CLR would have to perform an additional search for the Print method, and either call it or throw a runtime error....I was not aware of this and it is really great.

Answer (score 1):

This is polymorphism in action. You declare `p1` thus:

```
parent p1 = new child();
```

So your reference to `p1` is as an instance of `parent`. That class doesn't contain a definition of `Print()`, thus the error on the line:

```
p1.Print();
```

If you change the declaration line to one of:

```
var p1 = new child();
```

or

```
child p1 = new child();
```

then the error will go away as you are then accessing `p1` as an instance of `child`.

Alternatively, you can declare `Print` in `parent` and override it in `child`:

```
public class parent
{
    public virtual void Print() { // do something }
}

public class child : parent
{
    public override void Print() { // do something else }
}
```

Comment: When I write parent p1 = new child(), so my understanding on this is that p1 is just a reference variable that is pointing to the actual child class object. So if I go by this so p1 is not an object of parent but the child...so why it go for parent class method

Comment: @BhuwanPandey, it is pointing to a child instance, but it's being referenced as a parent object. Thus you are restricted to methods declared in parent in this case. Understanding why that's the case will lead you to understand polymorphism :)

Comment: Thank You Dave, but actually if we write child c = new child(), here what is c ---its a reference variable and is allocated memory on the stack....now new child() will actually create an object and that will be allocated memory on the heap......Here, the c reference variable on the stack is pointing to the child object that is created on the heap.        Now, if I take parent p1 = new child() , here also the p1 reference variable will just point to the child object ....so how come new child() will create a parent object..............I'm totally confused